# Uploading Multiple Types of Files using Django Jquery File Upload

Tags: jquery, django

When searching for django jquery uploading library, I came across this one.
https://github.com/Alem/django-jfu

It seems to be very neat and useful. So, I decided to give it a shot and started to read the demo code. However, the highlighted line of code is hard to understand. It is in the file demo/photos/views.py

```
class Home( generic.TemplateView ):
    template_name = 'base.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super( Home, self ).get_context_data( **kwargs )
        **context['accepted_mime_types'] = ['image/*']**
        return context
```

If I want to configure it to be able to upload both pictures (.jpg, .png, etc.) and .pdf files. How shall the highlighted line be modified? I guess it is this one
context['accepted_mime_types'] = ['image/* text/plain']

Is this correct?

On the other hand, the photo_upload_form.html shall be changed FROM

```
{% block JS_OPTS %}
sequentialUploads: true,
acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(png|gif|jpe?g)$/i
{% endblock %}
```

TO

```
{% block JS_OPTS %}
sequentialUploads: true,
acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(png|gif|jpe?g|pdf)$/i
{% endblock %}
```

I added the pdf extension at the end.

In all, I could not find any django documentation explaining all possible content_type values such as 'json/application', 'image/*', 'text/plain'. What are other possible values?

Answer (score 0):

`'accepted_mime_types'` is a list, so you can add additional items to it:

```
context['accepted_mime_types'] = ['image/*', 'application/pdf']
```

A list of valid MIME types is [available on the IANA website](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). You can use a wildcard for the bit after the `/`, although you probably don't want to do that for anything other than images.

Comment: Thank you solarissmoke! Is it also necessary to add the pdf file extension to the photo_upload_form.html as shown above?

Comment: Yes. Your edit to the JS looks correct. Does it work?